# Bitwise operation OR on (double) in Java not possible, possible in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, numbers, double, bitwise-or

Here is outputs from Google Chrome Javascript Console.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gefcZ.png]

Here is outputs from DrJava Java Console.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ7hS.png]

My Javascript code is

```
(baseCPUCyclesPerIteration - CPUCyclesTotalRoundoff) | 0
```

Seems to compile fine in Java if both variables are integers but apparently they are doubles in javascript. Even though

`typeof baseCPUCyclesPerIteration` reveals `"number"`

The results make it pretty obvious it's a double datatype. I don't understand why bitwise `OR 0` works on a double in Javascript but doesn't work on Java double's.

Seems the purpose of the `| 0` is just to trim of the decimal points in double datatype. I'm guessing in Java the equivalent will be `(int)` or `(long)` cast is this correct? or the bitwise `| 0` does more then just trim of the decimal point in javascript?

Edit:
ya `| 0` doesn't just trim in javascript just ran this. `8899811111.111113453456754645 | 0` got back `309876519`.
(Although I passed the double limit lol still tries to compute it in javascript, I'm guessing this is where the overflows happen).

Comment: They handle types differently (your question seems legitimate, just saying :p, it's confusing to compare them)

Comment: Because in Java, bitwise operators can only be applied to primitive integer types... That is defined by the language.

Comment: is `| 0` same as `(int)` or `(long)` cast in Java?

Comment: No idea, but it would be better to use `parseInt()` (in JavaScript) imho. Otherwise yes, you'd cast in Java to remove decimals. Beware though that you want a `long` to handle all of `double` since possible integer values in `double` are larger than what an `int` supports

Comment: ya `| 0` doesn't just trim in javascript just ran this. `8899811111.111113453456754645 | 0` got back `309876519` (Although I passed the double limit lol still tries to compute it in javascript, I'm guessing this is where the overflows happen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, all bitwise operators will cast decimal numbers to 32 bit integers. It acts like `floor` for positive numbers and `ceil` for negative numbers. Things like `|0` or `~~` are often used as tricks to cast numbers to integer in JavaScript.

To explain the overflow you're seeing, we can look at the specifications for how Javascript converts numbers to int32: http://es5.github.io/#x9.5

> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts its argument to one of 2^32 integer values in the range −2^31 through 2^31−1, inclusive. This abstract operation functions as follows:
>
> 1. Let *number* be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If *number* is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.
> 3. Let *posInt* be sign(number) * floor(abs(number)).
> 4. Let *int32bit* be *posInt* modulo 2^32; that is, a finite integer value k of Number type with positive sign and less than 2^32 in magnitude such that the mathematical difference of *posInt* and k is mathematically an integer multiple of 2^32.
> 5. If *int32bit* is greater than or equal to 2^31, return *int32bit* − 2^32, otherwise return *int32bit*.

So, to reproduce this behavior, you would have to reproduce this logic.

**Edit:** Here's how Mozilla's Rhino engine does it in Java: (as per the github link supplied by user3435580)

```
public static int toInt32(double d) {
    int id = (int)d;
    if (id == d) {
        // This covers -0.0 as well
        return id;
    }

    if (d != d
        || d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        || d == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    d = (d >= 0) ? Math.floor(d) : Math.ceil(d);

    double two32 = 4294967296.0;
    d = Math.IEEEremainder(d, two32);
    // (double)(long)d == d should hold here

    long l = (long)d;
    // returning (int)d does not work as d can be outside int range
    // but the result must always be 32 lower bits of l
    return (int)l;
}
```

Comment: How would I replicate `19981111156.111113453456754645 | 0` which gives  `-1493725324` probably won't happen it will go that large, but just in case to be safe. Yeah it seems to overflow in 32 bit range. In Java `(int)19981111156.111113453456754645` gives `2147483647`

Comment: It seems like Java cuts off values at max int. I've updated my answer to explain (in the spec's words) this overflow behavior in JavaScript.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptRuntime.java#L1109  seems to be it, yup thats the answer. `toInt32(19981111156.111113453456754645)` becomes `-1493725324`